# Same dimen in App and Library

Tags: android, android-layout

Can someone let me know, what if there is some dimen by same name in app and a library.

**dimen.xml** inside **app**

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">10dp</dimen>
```

**dimen.xml** inside **library**

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">12dp</dimen>
```

Which one will be used at runtime?

I can try it, but I will not be clear for the reason to being used as final value.

Comment: Ofc I understand. AFAIK everything you redefine in the app values (strings, styles, colors, dimensions, etc.) is used instead the first definition on a library, framework or whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you redefine(the same name) a dimension resource is like overriding the lib resource.  
 Just like you override a class method.

Comment: Exactly________

Comment: One more thing, what if I create same dimen inside another `dimenss.xml` file?

Comment: I don't think that the compiler will allow it but I never tried this.

Comment: What if two library has same dimen. :D, just a question.

Comment: I guess there would be a conflict, but I guess... I have never encountered such a case and I hope I will not in the future

Answer (score 3):

You can try to redefine size in your `dimensions.xml`:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin" tools:override="true">12dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Use with care as this is a hack, not an actual solution. The solution might not work if the resource's name is changed in the future Library release.

Comment: Does tools:override mean this is final value?

Comment: Also what if I don't set `tools:override`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer would be:

It depends on what layout is being populated, if it's an activity layout from an app module then app's dimen will be used and vice versa..

Comment: I think there is no reason defined or I can not find in documentation. The only solution is now to try all the cases.

Comment: Yeah.. Check once by changing the dp value and then it will be clear.. For me too :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question I don't know why it got downvoted. While the selected answer is true there is slightly more nuance to it, Android chooses the "most specific" resource which takes precedence over app resource values.

e.g. consider the boolean `<bool name="isTablet">true</bool>` in a library, setup like so:

- **values** - false
- **values-sw600dp** - true

And in an app like so:

- **values** - false
- **values-sw600dp-land** - true

What is the value of the boolean on a 1280x800 portrait tablet when called from the app?

The answer is ***true***, even though the app specified it to be true in landscape only!